# Generics not so generic !

Tags: generics, scala

I tried to implement a generic binary search algorithm in scala. Here it is :

```
type Ord ={
def <(x:Any):Boolean
def >(x:Any):Boolean
}
def binSearch[T <: Ord ](x:T,start:Int,end:Int,t:Array[T]):Boolean = {
if (start > end) return false
val pos = (start + end ) / 2
if(t(pos)==x)         true
else if (t(pos) < x)  binSearch(x,pos+1,end,t)
else                binSearch(x,start,pos-1,t)
}
```

everything is OK until I tried to actually use it (xD) :

```
binSearch(3,0,4,Array(1,2,5,6))
```

the compiler is pretending that Int is not a member of Ord, but as I know class Int has `<`and `>` methods. 
Well what shall I do to solve this weird problem?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see that Ord is of type int looking at your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest is to use Scala's standard library `Ordered[T]` trait and its accompanying implicit instances.

By using a view bound `<% Ordered[T]`, Scala will look for an implicit `Ordered[T]` instance in scope and allow you to use any of its methods (e.g. `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `compare`) on the generic type.

Here's a slightly rewritten binary search function,

```
def binarySearch[T <% Ordered[T]](x: T, xs: Seq[T]): Int = {

  def searchBetween(start: Int, end: Int): Int = {
    if (start > end) return -1 // not found

    val pos = (start + end ) / 2

    if (xs(pos) == x) pos // found, return position
    else if (xs(pos) < x) searchBetween(pos+1, end)
    else searchBetween(start, pos-1)
  }

  searchBetween(0, xs.length)
}
```

You can then immediately use it with many common classes, such as `Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `String`, `BigInt`, ... basically any type for which Scala defines an `Ordering[T]` instance, or even provide your own by implementing an `Ordering[YourType]` and either passing it explicitly to `binarySearch()` or providing an implicit instance in the scope.

Here are examples with `Int`'s and `String`'s:

```
scala> binarySearch(2, Seq(1,2,3,4,5))                               
res1: Int = 1

scala> binarySearch("d", Seq("a","b","d","f"))   
res2: Int = 2
```

Comment: Thank you
I tried `<:Ordered[T]` but i didn't know the `<%` thing.

Comment: Your binary search is incorrect. Try `binarySearch(2, Seq(1))`. it'll go out of bounds

Answer (score 6):

Int is indeed not of type Ord. It has < and > , but the types are of Int, not Any.

I think you need to use type classes here:

```
trait Cmp[T] {
  def cmp(t1: T, t2: T) : Int
}

implicit object IntCmp extends Cmp[Int] {
  override def cmp(i1: Int, i2: Int) = i1 - i2
}

def binSearch[T](x:T,start:Int,end:Int,t:Array[T])(implicit c: Cmp[T]):Boolean = {
  if (start > end) return false
  val pos = (start + end ) / 2
  c.cmp(t(pos), x) match {
    case 0 =>  true
    case -1 =>  binSearch(x,pos+1,end,t)
    case _ => binSearch(x,start,pos-1,t)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you.
It's a bit complicated for me (I've just started learning scala) so I will just use a non generic method for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Drop your `Ord` type and change the type constraint `T <: Ord` to `T <% Ordered[T]`. Then all the types `T` that have implicit conversions to `Ordered[T]` (including the numeric types and `String`, e.g.) will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, why should Int be a subtype of Ord? It certainly is not declared to be.</strike>

This has nothing to do with generics, but plain OOP: an interface is only implemented if the implementing class, or one of its supertypes, are declared to implement it. You don't do that.

Edit: Turns out I was wrong. I leave this answer due to the helpful comments attached to it.

Comment: Any class that has the methods `<(Any)` and `>(Any)` is automatically a subclass of Ord the way he defined it. No need to declare it. The problem is just that Int doesn't.